# How to render twig template manually without escaping?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to render twig template manually, the code is like:

```
$template = $this->twig->loadTemplate('MyBundle::board.html.twig');                                          $result = $template->render(array('entities'=>$query->getResult()));  
return $result;
```

When I `echo $result`, everything works well, Chrome renders all HTML code correctly, but I need to return `$result` from a function, then render in twig as `{{result}}`, but I can not use `{{result|raw}}`.

Any other way to make twig don't escape html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why can't you use {{ result|raw }}. But escaping can be disabled for the whole environment. Here is something I have used for rendering some html from string, with escaping turned off.

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment( new \Twig_Loader_String(), 
    array(
        'autoescape' => false
    )
);
$body = $env->render(
    $templateString,
    $parameters
);
```

Though probably this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think the escaping should be inside  `MyBundle::board.html.twig`