# Not escaping HTML tags in twig so they display as markup

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Quick question for everyone,

Is there something i am missing, I have not been able to find the correct answer to this, or i am reading the results i find wrong.

```
Bascially, I have a variable in php 
ex $var="<b>#Something#</b>";

And i render it via TWIG like 

{{ var }}
```

I don't want it to actually render `<b>#Something#</b>`, 
But i want **#Something#**

Any ideas where i am failing at the simple task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default raw filter in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185878/set-default-raw-filter-in-twig)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render twig template manually without escaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631183/how-to-render-twig-template-manually-without-escaping)

Answer (score 13):

You can try `raw` method of twig

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

OR set `false` to `autoescape`

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ var }}{# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Reference: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html

Comment: I will try that way, When i did the {{ var|raw }} method, it was still showing up as <b> on the display.

Comment: So when i try those ways, I still see the <b> on the output, It doesn't act like it's being used as markup.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour in Twig is to escape the vars before displaying them.
If you don'y want the var to be escaped, you have to use the `raw` filter

```
{{ var|raw }}
```

[see the doc here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)